# How to pass interface modport signal into other module?

Tags: system-verilog

I'm trying to implement an interface with modports.  I have 2 modules inside a testbench.

```
module test;
test_intf intf();

clk_reset u_clk_reset (
            intf.CLK_RESET
                );

mem u_mem(
        intf.MEM
    );
....
endmodule
```

This is the interface:

```
interface test_intf;
logic reset_n;
logic aclk;
logic bclk;
logic areset_n;

logic               wr_in;
logic               rd_en;
logic    [ 9:0]     wr_addr;
logic    [23:0]     wr_data;
logic    [ 9:0]     rd_addr;
logic     [23:0]    rd_data;

modport CLK_RESET (output aclk, bclk, areset_n);
modport MEM (output rd_data, input clk, reset_n, wr_in, rd_en, wr_addr, wr_data, rd_addr);

endinterface
```

This is the `clk_reset` module:

```
module clk_reset(
test_intf intf
);


always #(5) intf.aclk = ~intf.aclk;
initial begin
 intf.aclk = 0;
end

initial begin
 intf.areset_n = 1;
 #2000  intf.areset_n = 0;
 #2000  intf.areset_n = 1;
end
```

This is the `mem` module:

```
module mem
        (
test_intf intf
);

always @(posedge intf.clk or negedge intf.reset_n)
begin
    //end
end
```

I checked that the `clk_reset interface` ports are working (all outputs).
But, the problem is that the output clock signals from `clk_reset` can't reach the `mem` module by interface. So, `intf.clk` signal is 'x' in the `mem` module.

How do I pass some interface's signals into another interface (module)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your simulator should have given you a compile error.  The interface is missing the declaration of the `clk` signal.  Add it like this:

```
logic clk;
```

Since you want to use `clk` inside `mem`, you need to add `clk` to the `CLK_RESET` modport list:

```
modport CLK_RESET (output aclk, bclk, clk, areset_n);
```

Finally, you need to generate the `clk` signal so that it is not X.  Here are the required changes:

```
interface test_intf;
    logic reset_n;
    logic aclk;
    logic bclk;
    logic clk;
    logic areset_n;

    logic               wr_in;
    logic               rd_en;
    logic    [ 9:0]     wr_addr;
    logic    [23:0]     wr_data;
    logic    [ 9:0]     rd_addr;
    logic     [23:0]    rd_data;

    modport CLK_RESET (output aclk, bclk, clk, areset_n);
    modport MEM (output rd_data, input clk, reset_n, wr_in, rd_en, wr_addr, wr_data, rd_addr);
endinterface

module clk_reset(
    test_intf intf
    );

    always #(5) intf.aclk = ~intf.aclk;
    initial begin
     intf.aclk = 0;
    end

    always #(5) intf.clk = ~intf.clk;
    initial begin
     intf.clk = 0;
    end

    initial begin
     intf.areset_n = 1;
     #2000  intf.areset_n = 0;
     #2000  intf.areset_n = 1;
    end
endmodule
```